# How do i render an object of unknown type in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I'm trying to find a way to render components that i know nothing about. Let me explain with the following example. I have a c# interface with a few implementations :

```
public interface IClassA
{
    //Some properties
}

public class ClassB : IClassA
{
    //Some implementation
}

public class ClassC : IClassA
{
    //Some implementation
}
```

with a page similar to the following

```
@page "/"

@foreach (var item in list)
{
    //How to display the item
}

@code {
    private List<IClassA> list = new List<IClassA>();

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            //Load data
        }
}
```

I am having trouble finding out how to be able to render the item without knowing the item class. The reason for this is i want to allow for others to implement the interface and a corresponding razor view
and my page would be able to use it. Is it even possible with Blazor?

I am using .Net 5 with the latest Visual Studio version, if it is relevant.

Edit : it seems this explanation is not sufficient. Let me add more information.

I am trying to make a Blazor module, a node based editor. As such, i can implement a few basic classes, but i want to be able to hadle custom and complex objects.
What i want is to make a few interfaces (INode, IInput, IOutput...) that will be managed by a NodeTree. Then, there will be a NodeTree component that will manage all the user interaction trough events. Since i am providing only the interfaces, the application using the module will provide the implementation and as such, it will also provide the views (razor components) that contains the markup to be used with each individual implementation.

For example, if they make an **IInput** implementation for a string, they will also provide a component with the markup similar to

```
<label>@input.Title</label>
<input type="text" @bind-value="@input.Value" />
```

Of course, this is a simplified example but it is intended for custom and complex objects, rather than the basic types.

I hope this gives more insight into my problem.

Comment: Do ClassB and ClassC implement IClassA ? If so, then why do you need to know what they are in your list - just treat them as implementations of IClassA

Comment: why do you care about the classes items , it doesn't matter if they implement your interface

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that i didn't properly copy the classes. Yes they implement the interface

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking, exactly?

If you want to implement members of the interface, then that's fine, go ahead.  If you want to add logic based on the implementation, you can also use the "is" keyword:

```
@if (item is ClassA){ 
   <ComponentForClassA ItemToRender=item />
}
else if (item is ClassB) { 
   <ComponentForClassB ItemToRender=item />
}
else {
   <GenericIClassAComponent ItemToRender=item />
}
```

So each component will have markup for displaying whatever is in that implementation.  But if you want to render an object about which you literally have NO information-- like what its members are, then start by figuring out the sound of one hand clapping. :D

Comment: The point is allowing other developers to make an implementation of the interface and the component that will know how to render it. My component should only know where to place that component in the page. Since i wont know what the component will be called, i can't add any if/else/switch/is branchings for it.

Comment: So far, I know: (1) you have a mysterious C# interface of some type.  (2) You want to display ANY implementation of that interface, by displaying who knows what properties using who knows what methods.  I read this as: "I want to display stuff in Blazor."  You'll have to explain what the contribution of these hypothetical "Other Developers" is supposed to be.  Will they provide a component with some markup?  Will they be implementing some kind of custom table interface you've made for them?  Non-zero info would be useful.

Comment: i've added more details in the original post, hope it's clearer as to what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i continued searching the web and found something that at least answers my question : no. What i wanted to do is not possible currently, at least not directly.

Here is the website explaining the workaround : [Blazor Dynamic Components](https://jonhilton.net/blazor-dynamic-components/)

The site also has a link to an issue talking about the same issue i have and Microsoft themselves don't seem to intend making that possible, here's the link for the issue : [Add DynamicComponent Component](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26781). At first glance it might seem like they answered the request, but it seems they didn't understand what was asked.

In any case, the current version of Blazor doesn't allow for what i want to do directly.